# Is ETH needed for all accounts to support gas fees

Tags: ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts, erc20

I would like to have some enlightment on ERC20 token:  If i create a token (let's say MTK ) to be use by a community and i send some of the tokens to each member of the community, does those members have to get ETH in order to use the MTK or they Can use the token whitout the need of having ETH?

I am thinking about using the admin address to get the necessary amount of ETH ( or other ERC20 token compatible crypto currencies) so that if that the that admin account will pay all occuring transactions fees (if needed).Therefore members won't have to deal with ETH and just use the community token.

Answer (score 2):

If it is an ERC20 token on the public mainnet network, someone (else) needs to pay for gas fees executing a transaction, there is no way to circumvent gas costs on L1/mainnet entirely.

What you are looking for are "meta-transactions" or "feeless" transactions: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/38479/how-to-make-someone-else-pay-for-gas

Comment: Ok fine. Thank you for the link